# A Strange Ending to a BasketBall Match

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba

Last week, when I switched on a Sports TV Channel, there was a re-telecast of one old NBA Match, probably from 2019. It was at the Ending Stage and I could not make sense of what was going on.

The teams were named "USA Something" and "World Something" ( having a "charity" or "friendly" match ? ) and all were Professional Players. The Scores were around 114 vs 124, with one team easily leading by 10 Points. There was about 5 minutes left in the match, but neither team was able to Score more Points.
When one Player got Possession of the Ball, he would go towards the Basket in a round-about way, with twists and turns, even though the opposite team did not block or oppose and prevent him.
When he tried to put the Ball in the Basket, he would ( Deliberately ? ) miss, even though he was close enough to easily Score Points.
At this moment, the other team would take the Possession of the Ball and repeat this.
Eventually, the match time ran out and the re-telecast ended.

A Strange Ending to a BasketBall Match !!!!

What was going on here ? NBA fans may throw more light on the Event.

Comment: This sounds highly likely to be the [Rising Stars Challenge, part of the All Star Weekend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rising_Stars_Challenge#2019_game), although honestly your description is so vague that it could be from almost any year.

Comment: @PhilipKendall , I think, based on your web-link, what I saw was a "Slam Dunk Contest" but strangely, nobody was trying to win. Maybe, "They were judged on artistic ability, imagination, body flow as well as fan response" from the Slam Dunk wiki. The Scores did not change because that was the Original Match; I guess, Slam Dunk is a Post Match Event. Thanks for the Input, I learnt about few more things, other than the "Standard" BasketBall Match !!